# Como inserir espaços em branco - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou fazendo uns exercícios e um deles me pede para criar um código que reproduza um "ASCII art ", li sobre e vi que era um caractere especial e tentei inserir o espaço na sua forma unicode "\s", "\u0020",mas sem sucesso. Vi algumas pessoas falando sobre usar expressões regulares. Agradeço desde já

```
<script>
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
for (var i =0;i<2;i++){
document.write("X   X<br>")
};
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
</script>


                      XXXXX
                      X   X
                      X   X   
                      XXXXX
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema do espaço, mesmo usando a entidade HTML `&nbsp;`, é a renderização dos caracteres. Em fontes proporcionais, cada caractere ocupa um espaço diferente de acordo com seu *width* (largura). Em fontes chamadas ***[monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces)*** (espaço único) qualquer caractere ocupa o mesmo espaço, como, por exemplo, a fonte Consolas, bastante usada em programação e, inclusive, é a fonte padrão deste editor de respostas, como mostra o print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que todas as fontes listadas acima são *monospaced*.

Exemplo da fonte Consolas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então você tem duas opções:

**1.** Usar a tag `<pre>`

A tag `<pre>` mostra o texto como ele é, já convertendo o tipo da fonte para *monospace*:

```html
<pre>
<script>
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
for (var i =0;i<2;i++){
document.write("X   X<br>")
};
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
</script>
</pre>
```

**2.** Usar a entidade `&nbsp;`:

Neste caso você precisa usar uma fonte *monospace*:

```css
body{
   font-family: consolas;
}
```

```html
<script>
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
for (var i =0;i<2;i++){
document.write("X&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;X<br>")
};
document.write("XXXXX<br>");
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigrado Sam, utilizei a  tag <pre> e funcionoou!!